# Make google maps polyline appear below street names?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm making a subway map. The "transit" option on the official google maps shows their polyline below street/town names, but I can't figure out how to make mine do the same. Changing the zIndex to 0 (or negative numbers) doesn't work. Anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same question.  Have you found a way to do this?

Comment: No, Tomik says there's no way to do it, unfortunately. Apparently the text is in the same plane as the image, as far as the API is concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps has several [panes](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapPanes) where the map components are being placed. Unfortunately for you the map tiles are placed below all those panes. Z-index has no effect if something is in higher pane, it only affects the order of overlays in the same pane. 
Moreover map tiles are single images where all the map data are rendered. Therefore you can't place an overlay below some of the data rendered on the map tiles.

Theoretically, there might be a way to achieve this, but it's very difficult and I'm not even sure if it would work. Using [styled maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#StyledMaps) you could create a base map type and an overlay map type. And then you could try to place the polylines between those two map types. Be sure there are many drawbacks:

1. I haven't tried to use styled map as an overlay map type so I'm not sure it would work.
2. Overlay map type is placed in the lowest map pane just above the base map. But polylines that are offered by Google Maps are rendered in higher pane and you can't place them into the lowest map pane.
3. Therefore it would be necessary to create your own special overlay layer or overlay map type containing the polylines. That is a lot of work! And then add it to the lowest map pane below the overlay map type.

OK, that's theory. Lots of hacking and uncertain outcome. I wouldn't do it that way!

Comment: Hmm. I was hoping there would be a straightforward way, considering google does it somehow. Thanks, though, I appreciate it.